# Forge: git pull not updating

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-forge

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "commit message"
$ git push
```

The code gets pushed to repo as expected. However
Forge deployment error message returns

> branch master -> FETCH_HEAD error: Your local changes to the following
>   files would be overwritten by merge: // ...files to change... Please,
>   commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. Aborting

How can I resolve this? 
Are my commits not merged? They are on my repository.
Do I need to stash? If so, what next??

Tried following other examples but unwilling to experiment without advanced knowledge of git.

Comment: The 3 commands you listed should not be generating that error message AFAIK.  Are you certain that you did not also do a `git pull` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-A` instead of `.` with `git add`

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "commit message"
$ git push
```

Now, try `git pull`.

**N.B:** `git add .` stage *modified* and *new* files and `git add -A` stage *modified*, *new* and *deleted* files.

Comment: What is the advantage of -A instead of add . ?

Comment: I guess you have deleted files and `.` does not stage deleted files. Can you see the output of `git status` after executed `git add .`?

Answer (score 0):

It is good use pull before push any project
just use * instead of .

```
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "commit message"
$ git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was because recently I ran composer update inside ssh

**Dont ever run composer update inside ssh. Run composer update inside VM / dev environment and run composer install inside ssh**

This resulted in changing server permissions

I was eventually able to fix this with 
chgrp -R forge:www-data /home/forge/mysite.com